# Calling a function that takes no parameter with a parameter in scheme

Tags: scheme

How does this code work? It does not seem like any of these functions have a parameter but yet you are able to call it with a parameter

```
(define (make-add-one)
  (define (inc x) (+ 1 x))
  inc)

(define myfn (make-add-one))

(myfn 2)
```

This runs and returns 3.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use substitution rules. `make-add-one`  can be rewritten like this:

```
(define make-add-one (lambda () 
  (define inc (lambda (x) (+ 1 x))
  inc))
```

Since `inc` is just returned we can simplify it further to this:

```
(define make-add-one (lambda () 
  (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)))
```

Now `myfn` we can replace the call to `make-add-one` with the code that the lambda has inside:

```
(define myfn (make-add-one)) ; ==
(define myfn (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)))
```

And at last, we can use substitution rules on the last call:

```
(myfn 2)                 ; ==
((lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) 2) ; ==
(+ 1 2)                  ; ==
3
```

Now `make-add-one` makes a new function that is identical to all other functions it makes. It doesn't really add anything. A good example of where this is useful is this example:

```
(define (make-add by-what)
  (lambda (value) (+ value by-what)))

(define inc (make-add 1))
(define add5 (make-add 5))

(map add5 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (6 7 8)
(map inc '(1 2 3))  ; ==> (2 3 4)
```

Just to see it's the same:

```
(add5 2)                         ; ==
((make-add 5) 2)                 ; ==
((lambda (value) (+ value 5)) 2) ; ==
(+ 2 5)                          ; ==
; ==> 7
```

And how does this work. In a lexically scoped language, all `lambda` forms captures the variables that are not bound in their own parameter list from the scope which it was created. This is known as a closure. A simple example of this is here:

```
(define x 10)
(define test 
  (let ((x 20)
    (lambda (y) (+ x y))))
(test 2) ; ==> 22
```

So in Scheme `test` uses `x` from the `let` even after the scope is out since the `lambda` was created in that scope. In a dynamically scoped language `(test 2)` would return `12` and the two previous examples would also produce other results and errors.

Lexical scoping came first to Algol, which is the predecessor to all the C language family languages like C, java, perl. Scheme was proably the first lisp and it was the essential design of the language itself. Without closure first version of Scheme was the same as its host langugage, MacLisp.

Answer (score 0):

Lift the definition of `inc` out of `make-add-one`:

```
(define (inc x) (+ 1 x))

(define (make-add-one)
  inc)
```

Now it's clearer that the expression `(make-add-one)` is the same as `inc`, and `inc` is clearly a procedure with one parameter.
In other words, invoking `make-add-one` with no arguments produces a procedure that takes one argument.

You can use the substitution method to follow the evaluation:

```
    (myfn 2)
==> ((make-add-one) 2)
==> (inc 2)
==> (+ 1 2)
==> 3
```